# it showing "undefined" in tree view using ASP.NET MVC with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

While fetching data from  the oracle database it showing "undefined" in Tree View structure using ASP.NET MVC and Gijgo tree view JQuery plug-in, The Tree View control can display a hierarchical (or nested, or recursive) collection of data in a tree of expandable nodes.. How to solve this?.Please, anyone helps me.

I am trying this link

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185174/How-to-create-Dynamic-draggable-and-droppable-Tree

[image: output image]

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Scripts/jqueryval") <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/conditional-validation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Gijgo/gijgo.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.gijgo.com/1.3.0/css/gijgo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //'Hierarchy/GetHierarchy'
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var Usertree = "";
            var tree = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: '/Hierarchy/GetHierarchy',
                success: function (records, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    tree = $('#tree').tree({
                        primaryKey: 'Id',
                        dataSource: records,
                        dragAndDrop: true,
                        checkboxes: true,
                        iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
                        //uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                    });
                    Usertree = $('#Usertree').tree({
                        primaryKey: 'ID',
                        dataSource: records,
                        dragAndDrop: false,
                        checkboxes: true,
                        iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
                        //uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                    });

                    tree.on('nodeDrop', function (e, ID, PID) {
                        currentNode = ID ? tree.getDataById(Id) : {};
                        console.log("current Node = " + currentNode);
                        parentNode = PID ? tree.getDataById(PID) : {};
                        console.log("parent Node = " + parentNode);

                        if (currentNode.PID === null && parentNode.PID === null) {
                            alert("Parent node is not droppable..!!");
                            return false;
                        }
                        // console.log(parent.HierarchyLevel);
                        var params = { id: ID, parentId: PID };
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Hierarchy/ChangeNodePosition",
                            data: params,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "Get",
                                    url: "/Hierarchy/GetHierarchy",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (records) {
                                        Usertree.destroy();
                                        Usertree = $('#Usertree').tree({
                                            primaryKey: 'ID',
                                            dataSource: records,
                                            dragAndDrop: false,
                                            checkboxes: true,
                                            iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
                                            //uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });

                    });

                    $('#btnGetValue').click(function (e) {
                        var result = Usertree.getCheckedNodes();
                        if (result == "") { alert("Please Select Node..!!") }
                        else {
                            alert("Selected Node id is= " + result.join());
                        }
                    });
                       //delete node
                    $('#btnDeleteNode').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var result = tree.getCheckedNodes();
                        if (result != "") {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/Hierarchy/DeleteNode",
                                data: { values: result.toString() },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("Deleted successfully ");
                                    window.location.reload();
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
                                },
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Please select Node to delete..!!");
                        }


                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });

            // show model popup to add new node in Tree
            $('#btnpopoverAddNode').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#modalAddNode").modal("show");
            });

            //Save data from PopUp
            $(document).on("click", "#savenode", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#formaddNode'));
                $('#formaddNode').validate();
                if ($('#formaddNode').valid()) {
                    var formdata = $('#formaddNode').serialize();
                    // alert(formdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Hierarchy/AddNewNode",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: formdata,
                        success: function (response) {
                            // $("#modalAddNode").modal("hide");
                            window.location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert('Exception found');
                            //  $("#modalAddNode").modal("hide");
                            window.location.reload();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            //  $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                        }
                    });
                }

            });

            //Close PopUp
            $(document).on("click", "#closePopup", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#modalAddNode").modal("hide");
            });

            $('.rbtnnodetype').click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).val() == "Pn") {
                    $('.petenddiv').attr("class", "petenddiv hidden");

                    $("#ParentName").val("");
                }
                else {
                    $('.petenddiv').attr("class", "petenddiv");
                }
            });

        });

    </script>

}
```

Comment: Can we see your backend code too please?

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (Nspira_DBContext entity = new Nspira_DBContext())
            {
                var plist = entity.TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS.Where(p => p.pid == null).Select(a => new
                {
                    a.id,
                    a.NAME
                }).ToList();
                ViewBag.plist = plist;
            }
            GetHierarchy();
            return View();
        }

Comment: List<TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS> hdList; List<HierarchyViewModel> records; using (Nspira_DBContext entity = new Nspira_DBContext()){  hdList = entity.TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS.ToList();
records = hdList.Where(l => l.pid == null)
                    .Select(l => new HierarchyViewModel
                    {
                        id = l.id,
                        NAME = l.NAME,
                        pid = l.pid,
                        children = GetChildren(hdList, l.id)
                    }).ToList();
            }            return this.Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Data bind in backend.But it doesn't show front end

Comment: Are you sure you have the same names as in the example, for example the 'text'?

Comment: no i am using different column name.ID,NAME,PID

Comment: Now i am trying same name also.it is not working.

Comment: It should really work with the value to be there to 'text', make sure 'text' is all lowercase. Can you also check the network tab of the browser to see what data is been send over the wire...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169747/discussion-between-revathi-vijay-and-jelle-oosterbosch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you name the property “text”, including lowercases, as the library binds this field to the label. Not having a property with this name renders it undefined.